# Phaser Audio Support in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, audio, phaser-framework

No matter what I try, I cannot get any audio files to play in Internet Explorer (11) when using Phaser.  I have tried both mp3 and m4a (encoded using default settings in Audacity).

Also, I have tried loading all Audio examples on the Phaser site in Internet Explorer (http://examples.phaser.io/) and none of these seem to load either.

I can get ogg files to play fine in Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but that's about it.

I found another forum where a user mentioned that they used Audacity to convert to mp3 and had success:
http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/5682-audiofiles-wav-and-ogg-not-loaded-in-internet-explorer/

But I am not having any luck.

Any ideas?  I can provide any more detail as necessary.

Thanks for your time and your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE11 cannot play m4a files. Well, it's a little more complex than this - it can't play them *unless* you have iTunes (or similar codec installing software) installed. Therefore you can't count on it working reliably for everyone.

It can however play mp3s, but it depends entirely on how you have encoded them. Not all mp3s are created equal. I would suggest you 'borrow' some mp3s from an official IE Audio demo [like this one](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Browser/AudioExplosion/Default.html) to use for testing. If these work then the issue is the mp3s you've created. If they don't work either, the issue is somewhere in your code.

However, as you said the official examples don't work in IE11 for you, I wouldn't rule out it being something local to your PC either, as they do actually work fine. A driver / codec issue quite possibly.

Comment: Hi Rich -- thanks for the response.  The IE Audio demo also didn't play music for me in IE.  So, I'm thinking there's something up with my PC.

I don't believe there's anything wrong with my code (For my test I'm using the Basic Project template on Github, and just adding my own MP3 file to play on the Main Menu).

It's probably out of the scope of the Phaser library, but is there anywhere we can find optimal browser settings to pass on to our users?  One of the reasons why I chose an HTML5 Game library was because I hoped it could be used without installing plugins/changing configurations.

Comment: I don't think there are many settings in IE you can change re: audio. Under "Internet Options - Advanced" there is a "Multimedia" section (quaint!) which includes things like "Enable alternative codecs" and "Play sounds in webpages" - but that's it. I would try hitting the "Reset" button to take it back to the 'factory' defaults and see what happens. That is what the vast majority of your users will be using anyway.

Comment: So, it turns out that "Play sounds in webpages" did the trick (I also reinstalled IE to get a complete fresh start). Turns out, that setting isn't checked by default, which makes absolutely makes no sense to me.  In any case thanks for your help.  I did notice sound behavior still a little different IE (when spamming 'play' for example) but that's a problem for another day. Thanks again for all you do -- looking forward to your next book!